# How to subtract the minimum value from an indexed value of a list?

Tags: python

So I have a `list`, well a `tuple` now, that i want to subtract the calculated minimum for each value in the list/tuple. I used `enumerate()` to set a counter but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go. All I know is that I can't straight up subtract a list from a list. So any help would be great, sorry I'm a newbie.

I've tried `map()` to apply a function to each iterable

`map(set(tuple) - set(minimum))`

```
original_list = [['str1',2.33,7.46, 0.499],['str2', 45.55,4.77,6.22]]
```

```
tuple = [1, ('str1', 7.46,9.37,9.54,9.03,10.7)]
[2, ('str2', 2.46,9.37,9.54,9.03,10.7)]
```

```
min():
  columns = list(zip(*file))
  minimum = [min(list(x for x in column[1:] if x is not None)) for column in 
  columns

  # minimum = [7.46, 2.46]
```

where minimum is generated from a function

`a = tuple - minimum`

theoretically 1, x1, x2, x3 need to subtract minimum 7.46 then 2, x1, x2, x3 need to subtract 2.46 or min2 in minimum list.

in other words, is there a way that I can do something like this but with another list?

```
for i in range(len(tuple)):
  tuple[i] -= corresponding minimum value from minimum()
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to subtract from? should the minimum be subracted from every other element? What output are expecting from to get from the `original_list`?

Comment: sorry, it's the minimum value of the list and yes the min needs to be subtracted from every element that is a float value (i.e. not None or str).

Comment: So `[[a - min(i[1:]) for a in i[1:]] for i in original_list]` for example?

Comment: expected output would be:  ```num  = element - minimum of  list```  i.e if  ```min = value of column1 = 1``` then expected output of column1 = [ 0.00, 9.00, 9.00] would be ```[0.00,8.00,8.00]```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
data = ('str1', 7.46,9.37,9.54,9.03,10.7)
l = [x - min(data[1:]) if type(x) == float else x for x in data] #substract minimum from x if x is a float, else leave x as it is
```

However, the type stuff makes it a bit ugly. Maybe, if the data always look like [ "str", float, float, float, ...] you can do something like this:

```
data = list(data)
minimum = min(data[1:])
l = data[:1] + [x - minimum for x in data[1:]] #leave data[0] as it is, but substract minimum from each x of data[1:]
```